# Javascript No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource on load of different url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load value from different url to a div, When that is loaded it gives me an error. I tried to google a lot. I didn't find a fix. I am aware that this question is already asked but still nothing solved my problem.

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://bulksms.icubetech.com/api/checkbalance.php?user=&pass=. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.w3schools.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("http://bulksms.icubetech.com/api/checkbalance.php?user=&pass=");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you run this page on a localhost or external server?

Comment: in localhost and i to tried on w3school both the place that is giving me the same error

Comment: @MariusBalaj, that won't change anything :-) @Shaik, this is because the `http://bulksms.icubetech.com/api/` server doesn't allow cross-origin requests, which you are doing by calling `jQuery.load()` method from outside one of their pages. The only solutions are : **1** Change the server config so it does allow such requests (not easy if it's not your server), **2** use a proxy server.

Comment: Like @Kaiido said: Google how to set up a reverse proxy with Apache (in assumption your application is hosted there)

Comment: thanks for the reply but am not aware of proxy server vl check if u can help that would be more use full

Comment: @Shaik that would be too broad for stackoverflow's standards sorry. There are a lot of ways of doing it, which will all depend on your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The response you get from `http://bulksms.icubetech.com/api/checkbalance.php` should include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in it's header.

It should be something like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: yoursite.com
```

You can't access this site via ajax if the above requirement is not fulfilled.

---

Alternatively, you can use a proxy php script to get this done. The idea is to get a php script in your own domain to talk to the site you are trying to access and give you the result. This will not raise any cross domain issues since your browser communicates only with a php script in your own domain. Here is a sample proxy script. Please change it to suite your needs.

```
<?php

// Allowed hostname
define ('HOSTNAME', 'http://Your_Server/');

//returns the headers as an array
function getHeaders()
{
    $headers = array();
    foreach ($_SERVER as $k => $v)
    {
        if (substr($k, 0, 5) == "HTTP_")
        {
            $k = str_replace('_', ' ', substr($k, 5));
            $k = str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower($k)));
            $headers[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $headers;
} 

// Get the REST call path from the AJAX application
$path = $_REQUEST['path'];
$url = HOSTNAME.$path;

// Open the Curl session
$session = curl_init($url);

// If it's a POST, put the POST data in the body
if ($_POST['path']) {
 $postvars = '';
 while ($element = current($_POST)) {
  $postvars .= key($_POST).'='.$element.'&';
  next($_POST);
 }
 $postvars = substr($postvars, 0, -1);  // removing trailing &
 $postvars = str_replace('xml_version', 'xml version', $postvars);  // fix xml declaration bug?
 $postvars = stripslashes($postvars);

 curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
}
else {
 //If it's a post, but not a form post (like a SOAP request)
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST') {
  curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

  $headers = getHeaders();
  $header_array = Array( "Content-Type: text/xml", "SOAPAction: " . $headers['SOAPAction']);
  curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_array);
  curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
 }
}

// Don't return HTTP headers. Do return the contents of the call
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Make the call
$xml = curl_exec($session);

// The web service returns XML. Set the Content-Type appropriately
header("Content-Type: text/xml");

echo $xml;
curl_close($session);

?>
```

Comment: put the php is not in my server that is third party

Comment: Either the website you are trying to access should send the headers needed to pass security or you should be able to bypass this through your server scripts. You can't get the wonders to happen around your site.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this request is failing is because the remote domain you are trying to make an AJAX request to doesn't send proper [`CORS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers. So the browser will block the request. You should talk to the administrators of the `bulksms.icubetech.com` to explicitly enable CORS for your own domain.

Comment: no, it doesn't **send** the headers, but I'm pretty sure it does support it.

Comment: From a client perspective that's equivalent :-) But thanks for nitpicking.

Comment: No, otherwise your advice wouldn't be possible at all

Answer (score 0):

This issue apparently has nothing to do with your front end code.
The server you are trying to access should allow requests from other domains.
In your case bulksms.icubetech.com does not allow CORS request from domain www.w3schools.com.